# Statistical model with an independent variable which has already adjusted by age

Tags: regression

I am working on a project which age and sex are not related to my continuous independent variable (Z)as it has already adjusted for age and sex. Now does it statistically make sense to have a regression  model including Z,age and sex as independent variables in the model? Or I need to have the regression model between y and Z?

Comment: What is y? How did you adjust for sex and age?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Knarpie I am interested in exactly what you are doing. What are your variables? What is your hypothesis? What are your research questions?

However, in general, the fact that the different independent variables are not related to each other is no reason not to include them in a regression model.  Indeed, having uncorrelated IVs makes some things easier.

Are age and sex related to the dependent variable?

Do you want to control for age and sex in the relationship between Z and Y?  (By the way, it's unusual to use Z for an independent variable, most people use X).